# Why does /execute store refuse to update an NBT number when provided with a scoreboard value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here are some commands for you to try in MCJE 1.16. Run the following commands in the chat:

1. Set up a scoreboard objective. (or use an existing test objective if you hate piling them up, like me)

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add test dummy
   ```
2. Set your own score. Set it to a number you'll remember. Make it low, like 5.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @s test 5
   ```
3. Give yourself a diamond sword with enchantments. Give it a level of a different number than you picked in step 2. I pick 9.

   ```
   /give @s diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:9s}]}
   ```
4. Try to set the diamond sword's enchantment level to the number in the scoreboard. This is the command I used:

   ```
   /data modify entity @s Inventory[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}].tag.Enchantments[{id:"minecraft:sharpness"}].lvl short 1 run scoreboard players get @s test
   ```

What this command *should* do is get your `test` score and store it in the Sharpness level of the diamond sword. But it doesn't. The level remains 9.

Here is another example with shorter commands. Do steps 1 and 2 like normal, but here's where we'll change things up:

3. Give yourself a piece of dirt. (any item will do)

   ```
   /give @s dirt
   ```
4. Modify the *count* of that dirt stack by setting it to the scoreboard value.

   ```
   /execute store result entity @s Inventory[{id:"minecraft:dirt"}].Count byte 1 run scoreboard players get @s test
   ```

Does the count of items modify? For me, it doesn't.

I tested this out using a command chain. Peeking into the command block for command #4, I can see the correct scoreboard value returned: `ExpertCoder14 has 5 test`, but the scoreboard value still isn't updated.

I checked all the fields, and they were all correct:

- **NBT path:** I used `/data get` with the same NBT path and got back the old value. This means I am using the correct path to target the value to update.
- **Scale:** I checked the [Minecraft Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#Store_subcommand) on `/execute store`. The scale is a number that the command result will be multiplied by before storing. I set it to `1.0`. This should be correct.

I also ran some additional trials:

- I used the `if` subcommand to test for a number of entities instead of `/scoreboard players get`. Here was a command:

  ```
  /execute store result entity @s Inventory[{id:"minecraft:dirt"}].Count byte 1 if entity @e
  ```

  Sample output:

  ```
  Test passed, count: 14
  ```

But the NBT value doesn't change!

Am I doing something wrong? Is this behaviour normal? Is there a bug report that I missed? What is going on?

Comment: The [wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/data#Result) says that the data command fails if you try to edit a player's data

Comment: @Macks What counts as player data?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Any data that would show up with /data get entity @s

Answer (score -1):

You can't modify player nbt.  You have to move the item to a container modify the conatiner's item.  Then loot the item back into the player's inventory.  The following link shows you how to edit items in a player's hand.  [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376895/is-it-possible-to-change-part-of-the-nbt-of-a-held-item).  I hope this helped.

Comment: Could you expand this answer to include all the information that I’ll need without directing me to external sites? It’s a rule here, because if you direct me to an external page, you are basically deferring the answering to someone else.

Comment: ok ill edit the answer

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I updated the answer go check it out.  Its on the duplicate.